# WebFlux - ignore 'cancel' signal

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Tried to get the answer from other SO q&a, directly from reactor's documentation and spring webflux documentation but somehow I am not sure still, how to achieve this :(

Say I have simple controller as follows:

```
@RestController
class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/demo/{text}")
    public Flux<String> getDemo(@PathVariable String text) {
        return Flux.fromArray(text.split(""))
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1L))
            .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("S: " + s + " -> " + LocalDateTime.now().getSecond()))
            .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("Cancelled"));
    }
}
```

and I would like the processing to ignore "cancel" signal, that normally comes when client disconnects. Tried to achieve that via nginx's `proxy_ignore_client_abort on;` but that does not work properly.

I can `.subscribe(...)` to a custom subscriber, that in example ignores `cancel` signals, but than I saw the processing is executed twice - which is quite obvious and not anticipated.

Another option, is that I can  `extends Flux<T>` and just override:

```
@Override
public void cancel() {
    System.out.println("Cancelled / ignored");
}
```

but that somehow looks more like hacking.

### To sum up

Could someone please advise, what is the "proper" way of running some reactive pipeline, triggered via controller, that can ignore cancel signal?

Comment: Why do you want to ignore this? The reactive pipeline is supposed to emit only the when the subscriber is still listening rt? If the subscriber is not interested, Do you still want to emit?

Comment: @vins - fair question, thx; the logic behind, is that once client evokes given action - it "must run", irrespective of cancelation from the client side; let's say the call initiated some process that cannot be rolled-back / reverted, and client timed-out, but still can get "results" of such operation via different operation; I know we could consider different patterns but I am just curious about particular case - ignore "cancel" signal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current webflux behavior is perfect. However your requirement seems to be different that you always want to emit even when the subscriber is no longer is interested in listening to the data. In this case, just make the source HOT.

```
@RestController
class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/demo/{text}")
    public Flux<String> getDemo(@PathVariable String text) {
        return Flux.fromArray(text.split(""))
                .map(String::toUpperCase)
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1L))
                .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("S: " + s + " -> " + LocalDateTime.now().getSecond()))
                .doOnCancel(() -> System.out.println("Cancelled"))
                .cache(); // hot source
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, looks promising - in fact, the `.cache(0)` should the work just fine, in my context;
I am, however, quite curious - why such approach is "better" than overriding `cancel()`? Could you please share your view on that?

Comment: You can also implement your own processor. But It seems to be unnecessary. You are responsible for all the testing to ensure that it works fine and does not cause any other issues. Reactor recommends to use the existing ones. https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#processors